# Moderator misusing his powers

Tags: discussion, moderation

I wrote a very beautiful (non copied) answer to a question. The question was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668829/how-to-find-the-value-of-xy-in-the-following-equation/4668838#4668838)

As you people can't see, I got $7$ upvotes on that answer. Now that question was closed because of a duplicate. I thought that I can also write the same answer on the question that was asked before. So I wrote the exact same answer [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3385514/determine-xy-where-x-and-y-are-real-numbers-such-that-2x12y2y-2x/4669329#4669329)

Then a moderator named Xander Henderson told me that I should not post multiple answers. Everything was okay. Since I was going to sleep, I decided that I will delete the answer that I posted on the question that was asked before, tomorrow.

But then when I woke up, I saw one of my answers deleted. And to my surprise, I was the one that I answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4668829/how-to-find-the-value-of-xy-in-the-following-equation/4668838#4668838) post, the one with $7$ upvotes.

I think if it was so much necessary to delete one of the answer, Xander could have deleted the one with no upvotes. It cost me $70$ reputation points and it was also my most voted post until it was deleted.

He's a moderator and doesn't even know the right thing to do. Why did he delete the answer that had upvotes instead of the answer with $0$ upvotes. In my opinion this is just **misusing the powers**

Or is it the protocol$?$ To delete answers that many people found useful and not deleting the one which apparently no one has seen.

I demand justice and once again it is proved that **MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad**

Comment: Having the same answer copy-pasted in two places is not okay. Keeping the version on a closed question helps nobody, so it was deleted, in favour of keeping the version on an open question. This is standard nas reasonable, and you have no right to claim a misuse of power nor to make personal attacks on the capability of a moderator doing the correct thing.

Comment: If they are indeed the same post, it doesn't matter which one is seen more, since they are the same content. Looks more like you're upset at losing rep because your post was in the wrong place. All you've proved is that your understanding of Math SE is bad.

Comment: Since the only ones who can help you are the moderators, perhaps you should engage them in the moderator's chat room, instead of ranting uselessly here on meta.

Answer (score 10):

> I think if it was so much necessary to delete one of the answer, Xander could have deleted the one with no upvotes.

Quality of the site, not any individuals reputation point level, is the standard that drives these decisions.

> He's a moderator and doesn't even know the right thing to do. Why did he delete the answer that had upvotes instead of the answer with 0 upvotes

I'm guessing he, or another moderator, will come along and give the exact reason, but a sensible guess is that we'd keep the one on the unclosed question.

It does suck that you've lost all that rep. And I'm wondering that if your main concern is gaining rep, then the better move would have been to just leave your high-rep version up. And if that's so, there's room for a meta question asking if the incentive system is working badly here, as moving a (good) answer to the open post might be better for the site.

If you'd posted asking about that, you might get some traction. Or you could delete this post, and make a better one based on that. But as is

- you're accusing mods of abusing their power, which is almost always b.s.,
- your concern is for your rep, not the quality of the site, and
- this might just be personal with me, but for quite a while your user name had been "MathStackexchangeIsVeryBad", which gave me very little sympathy for your participation here,

so I don't think you'll get much satisfaction from the responses you get to this post.

Answer (score 9):

The answer you seem to be referencing is https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4668838/, which is in response to a Problem Statement Question, which was closed as a duplicate.  This *question* should probably be deleted (and, in fact, has already attracted a delete vote).

You posted an identical answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4669329/.  The question is of moderately higher quality (it even includes a source!), has been on the site longer, as has been marked as a duplicate target of the previous question.

As a moderator, my goal is to preserve the better content.  In this case, the older question *is* the better content.  Since you provided the same answer in two places, I had to make a decision about which to delete.  It seemed like a no brainer to preserve the answer which is attached to the older, slightly better written, non-closed question; and to delete the answer which is attached to the newer, lower-quality, no-closed-and-likely-to-be-deleted question.